# Best Practices on BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls, backgroundworker

I am making my first ever C# GUI. It is using a `BackgroundWorker` to run a computationally heavy simulation. Periodically, the simulation reports (through the `ProgressChanged` event) a sizable body of information that needs to be displayed in the GUI.

The GUI is divided into controls and I want each control to know how to 'update itself'.

In my research, I found lots of ways I might be able to do this.

- I could think of was to have the method bougnd to `ProgressChanged` call an update method on each part of the GUI.
- I could `Invalidate` the GUI and bind each controls update method to the `Validating` event.
- I could bind each control's update method to the `ProgressChanged` event.
- I could have each control implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (but I'm skeptical that this would work)

Of all of these options, which one is best practices for updating the entire GUI upon the `ProgressChanged` event? (or am I out in left field?)

From comment:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Simulation simulation = new Simulation();
  while(true)
  {
    simulation.RunIteration();
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(-1, simulation);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `ProgressChanged` reports a large amount of data that is then 'split' among multiple controls? Can you give a brief code example of how the `ProgressChanged` event handler is currently raised?

Comment: @IAbstract The simulation is repetedly looping in the backGroundWorkerObj_DoWork as `while(true){ simulation.RunIteration(); backgroundWorkerObj.ReportProgress(-1, simulation); }`. Each iteration raises a ReportProgress event. Sorry for the formatting. I can't figure out how to add carriage returns in mini-Markdown.

Comment: "I could bind each control's update method to the ProgressChanged event."  That one sounds right to me.  Each control doesn't need to know about the others, they all simply depend on the same event occurring.

Comment: It is a 'Windows Forms Application'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have to do anything special.

Your ProgressChanged handler can 'unpack' the data and set the relevant properties of controls. Invalidation and repainting is automatic and it runs on the GUI thread.

You should only be careful with updating 'too often'. How often is too often depends on the volume of data, the handler should be finished well before the next update. If not, build in some throttling mechanism.

Comment: Humm. This seems like a **`ProgressChanged` watch controls** paradigm. Is it possible/good to have a **controls watch `ProgressChanged`** paradigm? It seems like a hassle to need to modify the `ProgressChanged` event handler code every time I (or even more troublesome, the GUI itself) adds a new component to the GUI. Is a **controls watch `ProgressChanged`** paradigm a good idea? Thanks!

Comment: Controls don't watch anything. It's an eventhandler in an eventdriven system. In WPF you can update a ViewModel and leaved the rest to databinding.

Comment: My bad. I meant to have the control's update function watch for an event raised by the ProgressChanged handler (I can't seem to bind a method directly to the ProgressChanged event. Is there something I'm missing?)

Comment: You're trying way too hard. @georgepotter has a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressBar is the method I recommend. If the data you want to send to the GUI is text then you could have a rich textbox or just a regular textbox and pass text to it when the progress bar is changed:

```
public void SomeThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    /* Update progress bar */
    ProgressBar.Value = (e.ProgressPercentage);
    if (e.UserState != null)
    {
        TextBox.Text += (string)e.UserState;
    }
}
```

For other forms of data you could include an If statement which does X when the progress bar is given a certain value.

But ithout knowing more about what you're specifically trying to do I'm afraid I can't provide any more help than that.

Comment: `ProgressChanged` runs on the BackgroundWorker thread; you have to marshal to the UI thread via `Invoke` or such.

Comment: @DourHighArch - No, an essential feature of the Bgw is that ProgressChanged is raised on the parent (GUI) thread.

Comment: @Henk is right! I just tried this on a blank new WinForm and it was raised on the parent. I must be doing something wrong in my app...